# Frame animation from images. Pygame (python3)

Tags: image, animation, python-3.x, frame, pygame

I have files (*.png) with animation. Each file - frame. So 10 files - 10 frames. Full animation repeat 4 times. So I need render images 20 times.

```
DiceAnim1=pygame.image.load('Gfx/Dices/dice0042.png').convert_alpha()
DiceAnim2=pygame.image.load('Gfx/Dices/dice0043.png').convert_alpha()
DiceAnim3=pygame.image.load('Gfx/Dices/dice0044.png').convert_alpha()
DiceAnim4=pygame.image.load('Gfx/Dices/dice0045.png').convert_alpha()
DiceAnim5=pygame.image.load('Gfx/Dices/dice0046.png').convert_alpha()
DiceAnim6=pygame.image.load('Gfx/Dices/dice0047.png').convert_alpha()
DiceAnim7=pygame.image.load('Gfx/Dices/dice0048.png').convert_alpha()
DiceAnim8=pygame.image.load('Gfx/Dices/dice0049.png').convert_alpha()
DiceAnim9=pygame.image.load('Gfx/Dices/dice0050.png').convert_alpha()
DiceAnim10=pygame.image.load('Gfx/Dices/dice0051.png').convert_alpha()
```

Can anyone suggest function with minimal code length.
Initiation in main programm loop:

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if gameState==7:
        if 165<pointer_coord[0]<424 and 249<pointer_coord[1]<607 : 
            gameState=9
            rolling=1
```

This is mean is user click in area (x=165, y=249, length=424-165, height=607-249), then game enter to state 9. State 9 - was created for playing animation.

```
if gameState==9:
        RollingAnimation(166,253)
        RollingAnimation(210,278)
        RollingAnimation(166,303)
        RollingAnimationControl()
```

This function RollingAnimation is:

```
def RollingAnimation(tx,ty):
    global diceTikTac
    screen.blit(DiceAnimShadow,[tx,ty])
    if diceTikTac==1: screen.blit(DiceAnim1,[tx,ty])
    if diceTikTac==2: screen.blit(DiceAnim2,[tx,ty])
    if diceTikTac==3: screen.blit(DiceAnim3,[tx,ty])
    if diceTikTac==4: screen.blit(DiceAnim4,[tx,ty])
    if diceTikTac==5: screen.blit(DiceAnim5,[tx,ty])
    if diceTikTac==6: screen.blit(DiceAnim6,[tx,ty])
    if diceTikTac==7: screen.blit(DiceAnim7,[tx,ty])
    if diceTikTac==8: screen.blit(DiceAnim8,[tx,ty])
    if diceTikTac==9: screen.blit(DiceAnim9,[tx,ty])
    if diceTikTac==10: screen.blit(DiceAnim10,[tx,ty])
```

To control animation I use a control function RollingAnimationControl:

```
def RollingAnimationControl():
    global radiobuttonPos,diceTikTac,round1,gameState
    diceTikTac=diceTikTac+1
    if diceTikTac==11: 
        round1=round1+1
        diceTikTac=1
    if round1>4: # how much need loops animation.
        gameState=11
        diceTikTac=1            
        rolling=0
        round1=0
```

Question is: How I can minimized this function. Can you imagine how would looks this function if animtion was use 100 files with frames.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your code as you have it written.  Can you put the entire thing with nothing splitted or put out of order or abbriviated, etc.  Thank you, and I will try to figure out your problem once you do.

Comment: I have 10 files and want make a animation. That's all.

Comment: I try to modify my question.

Comment: If anyone know better method of loading images - please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For loading the animations, you can use a for loop to go through the things you need to load, because of their convinient naming (good job on that):

```
frames=[]
for i in range(42, 52):
    frames.append(pygame.image.load('Gfx/Dices/dice00'+str(i)+'.png').convert_alpha())
```

Now that the frames are all in a list, it makes it much easier to blit them.

```
for frame in frame:
    screen.blit(frame, ???)
```

In this way, you can blit and load your animation without any long or repetative

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use sprite sheets for animation.

## animation loading:

```
def load_anim(start=42, stop=52):
    # loads array of many frames
    files = [ "Gfx/Dices/dice00{}.png".format(i) for i in range(start, stop) ]
    frames = []

    for file in files:
        surf = pygame.image.load(file).convert_alpha()
        frames.append(surf)
    return frames
```

I'm not sure how you are animating. If it's time based, or what?

## clicking

```
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
    if gameState==7:
        # I'm assuming this is the rect of a sprite.
        # Otherwise you can still create the Rect
        if dice_sprite.get_rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
            gameState = 9
            rolling = 1
```